# How to convert 1 to Yes or 0 to No in array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have data which is coming in 1 and 0 from db and I need to show in UI Yes and No. I am using for (const obj of arr1) and map like stuff and still not able to get the desire output.

```
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Emp1', lc: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Emp2', lc: 0},
  {id: 3, name: 'Emp3', lc: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Emp4', lc: false},
];
```

I need to convert this array this way

```
const newArr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Emp1', lc: "Yes"},
  {id: 2, name: 'Emp2', lc: "No"},
  {id: 3, name: 'Emp3', lc: "Yes" },
  {id: 4, name: 'Emp4', lc: "No"},
];
```

Comment: what you tried ?

Comment: use Array `map` for a start

Comment: and a ternary expression. `value ? 'Yes' : 'No'`

Comment: Currently, I am doing for Yes or No.. 
```
for (const obj of arr) {
  if (obj.lc = 1) {
    obj.lc = 'Yes';
  }
  else if(obj.lc = 0){
    obj.lc = 'No';
  }
  else {
    return null;
  }
}
const newArr = arr.map((lc = "1") => {
  return 'Yes';
});
```
I am new in CS

Comment: `const newArr = arr.map(({lc, ...rest}) => ({...rest, lc:lc?'Yes':'No'}))`

Comment: @JaromandaX
I tried that it's coming Yes for all lc

Comment: @XerYankZap - then your input data is not what you stated

Comment: @sp00m - I'll write an answer when the OP writes code :p

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```js
const arr = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Emp1', lc: 1},
  {id: 2, name: 'Emp2', lc: 0},
  {id: 3, name: 'Emp3', lc: true},
  {id: 4, name: 'Emp4', lc: false},
];

const newArray = arr.map((item) => ({
  ...item,
  lc: item.lc ? 'Yes' : 'No'
  })
  )
  console.log(newArray)
```

This creates a new array. `...item` puts in all the existing fields.
`lc: item.lc ? 'yes' : 'no'` basically creates a new value for `lc` where if the value is truthy (1, or true) it give you `Yes`, and otherwise if gives you `No`

Comment: Can you explain me how is  lc using if else logic?

Comment: @Yank, if you look up ternary operator you’ll get a better answer, but basically this reads as lc = depending on truthiness of value before the question mark, either the value before the colon or after the colon.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this.

```
const newArr = arr.map(elem => {
   elem.lc = elem.lc ? "Yes" : "No";
   return elem
})
```

Comment: this is the same answer as below already answered

Comment: @AbasahebGaware - except it isn't as confusing :p

Comment: This mutates the previous array

Answer (score -1):

just map and update it

```js
const newArr = arr.map((a)=>{
  a.lc = a.lc ? "Yes" : "No";
    return a;
});
```

Comment: mutating items in a map seems like a misuse of map

Comment: This has the side effect of updating the original array, in which case `forEach` should rather be used to make this more obvious. Ideally, make `map` return a new object.

Comment: @evolutionxbox meh